# How to get specific values out of a ruby on rails find_by_sql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have the following 2 files. One is the Model class, which has a function called getAverage, which gets the average of all the ratings of each model grouped by name. 
I tried the query in the pgadmin software, and it worked. However, when I used it in Ruby, the output was [#,#,#,#] for some reason.
Here are the two files:
models.erb

```
<h3>Current Ratings</h3>
<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
<h4>Book Name:Average Rating Table</h4>
<% @models.each do |model| %>
    <tr>
        <th><%= model.name %></th>
        <td><%= model.rating %></td>
        <td><%= Model.group(:name).select('name, avg(rating) as average_rating')[0] %> </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
<a href="/">Back to Home</a>
```

model.rb

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def getAverage(query)
    avgRatings = Model.find_by_sql(query)
  end
end
```

My output in the webpage: (Note that [#] should contain the model title and rating)

```
Book Test   23  [#, #, #, #]
Book Name   44  [#, #, #, #]
The Great Gatsby    55  [#, #, #, #]
```

Comment: Play around this in the console and see what you get before trying it out on the view.

Comment: You don't need `find_by_sql` for getting `avg`. You can do `Model.group(:name).select('name, avg(rating) as average_rating')` e.g.

Comment: @Iceman this is strange. I did exactly what you said, and for some reason it's showing as a '#' still

Comment: How are you doing it, could you update the question to show that perhaps.

Comment: It returns an array so you'll have to loop through it

Comment: I'm new to ruby, but this is what I did. <td><%= Model.group(:name).select('name, avg(rating) as average_rating')[0] %> </td>

Comment: Yes, you will also need to specify the attribute you want `[0].average_rating`

Comment: And, putting sql in the view is really bad practice, just a side note...